# Javascript dynamic added row is not responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, responsive-design

This is my empty table (when is empty the table is responsive):

```
<table class="table" id="tabla_lista_pedido">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Codigo</th>
  <th>Descripcion</th>
  <th>cantidad</th>
  <th colspan="2">Quitar de lista</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="tbody">

</tbody>
</table>
```

this is my js function, which add new row to the table

```
function get_current_producto(id, cod, desc){

     $("#tbody").append('<tr><td hidden="hidden">'+id+'</td><td>'+cod+'</td><td>$'+desc+'</td><td><input id="cantidad_pedido" min="1" max="100" type= "number">
</input></td><td><button class= "btn btn-danger btn-xs deleterow">X</button></td></tr>');

   }
```

Up to here the row is added ok, but the table row and so the thead are not responsive now! why? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'responsive' (typically 'responsive' in web-design refers to the ability of the contents to fit changing screen sizes)? I *think* you mean it's not responding to user-interaction and your JavaScript event-handling is being ignored, but I'm not sure. Regardless of that, though, can you share your (relevant) CSS as well, enough that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @DavidThomas i refer  to the ability of the contents to fit changing screen sizes. the new row makes the table lose this ability

Comment: Thanks, then you need to add enough of the "*[mcve]*" code to reproduce that responsive design :)

Comment: Have you tried to add the same rows (same content, same classes...) to the table manually? Does your table work the same way with static data?

Comment: My guess is the content inside is causing it not to flow. Maybe adding some styles to make the content fit their containers....

Comment: thank you all. The problem was caused by the input in the new row. It has no class. I add attribute class= "form-control" and now is working fine. thans you all!